# All input field should be in same line

Tags: html, css, forms

I am writing a html document in which the output is as follows:
[image]

I have two problems with it:
1. I want to line up the first three input fields.
2. Radio buttons are not working properly.

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>
            Contact Us
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleit.css"/>

        </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Contact Us </h1>
        <form id="form">
            Your Name : <input type = "text" value = "name" > </br>
            Mobile no : <input type = "text" value = " Mob" ></br>
            Email   :   <input type = "text" value = "Email"></br>
            Best time to call: <input type="radio" >evening 
                                        <input type="radio">morning </br>
            Languages: <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" > C
                          <input type="checkbox" > C++ <br>
                          <input type="checkbox" > C#
                          <input type="checkbox" > python<br>
                          <input type="checkbox" > Java 
                          <input type="checkbox" > CSS </input> <br>

            <input type="submit" value="submit">

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My css code is:

```
form input
{
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    }
h1
{
text-align:center;
 }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: First, you should add same name for radio input - `<input type="radio" name="time">`

Comment: name is required for server side use. Do I need it?

Comment: You need 'name' for radio to join it with value that you choose.

Comment: Then i think I have to add a lot of ids :)

Comment: <input name='radio1' value='A' type="radio" >evening 
<input name='radio1' value='B' type="radio">morning </br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your radio buttons is quite simple... you have to tell the browser in which "group" your radio button are, and this is done through the `name` attribute :

```
<input type="radio" name="bestTimeToCall">evening</input>
<input type="radio" name="bestTimeToCall">morning</input>
```

Aligning your form fiels is a bit more tricky and can actually be done several ways. One way would be to use a table and put your labels in first column and your fields in the second one. That's not optimal as you shouldn't use tables for that, but still for a beginner this is by far the easiest solution.

The best solution, but a bit more complicated, would be to use the `label` tag for your labels, and style this tag so that it's always the same width, meaning that the iput fields will all start at the same point, and look aligned.

Please note also that `<br>` can be written that way (in HTML 5) , or `<br/>` , but never `</br>`

Comment: Can we do without using table or label?

Comment: Any surrounding tag around your text nodes (=the text in front of your field) would do the same, but you will need one, and `<label>` tag is designed for that semantically. For example, using this tag together with its `for` attribute to link to the correct input will allow you to focus the field when clicking the label.

Comment: look, you do things like you want, it's not my code. Still `</br>` is not valid HTML and could be misinterpreted by some browsers now or in the future. If your goal is to do things like you want with no respect for standards, so be it, but don't be amazed when problems will come in the future...

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `name` property to your radio and checkbox input. you can read about some useful form tags [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Regarding the alignment, there are several ways to solve this, depending on what do you think it's the best way. You could for instance, use a table to arrange this kind of field, or add classes to you input fields and align them via css. I'd recommend using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to work this kind of thing, it's a very practical solution. But again, possibilities are nearly unlimited.

Comment: Isn't bootstrap a bit overkill in that case ?

Comment: @Bartdude I think it's good for beginners to start with a rather simple way of doing things the right way, and Bootstrap is a way for non-designers to make beautiful interfaces and forms without having to worry about other stuff. And if you're learning it's a good way to imbue yourself with some good practices :).

But I get your point, it can be a little "too much"

Comment: I see your point but I totally disagree with you. From where I see it , using frameworks like bootstrap isn't a good thing for beginners. They don't learn to do HTML, CSS, etc ... they learn to use the framework and that's it. So in the long-term, I don't think it's a good idea to take shortcuts without knowing the original way of doing stuff. If you teach your child how to bicycle before he learns how to walk, he may become a bicycle king, but it may be a problem when he doesn't have a bicycle...

Comment: I believe they DO learn a lot of HTML and CSS (and even less or sass for that matter) while using bootstrap. I feel the same way with other frameworks like Zend or Django, when they're really on another asbtraction level. To use bootstrab, knoledge about HTML and CSS (and good practices also) are a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Your Name :</label> <input type = "text" value = "name" >
<label<Mobile no :</label> <input type = "text" value = " Mob" >
<label>Email   :</label>   <input type = "text" value = "Email"
</label>Best time to call:</label> <input type="radio" name="time">evening 
<input type="radio" name="time">morning </br>
```

Add attribute - `name` for radio inputs.
Remove `<br />`
Add `<label>` with `display: inline-block`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7x6Pq/)